# installing tmux on Ubuntu 8.04

Tags: compiling, tmux

Spending the weekend getting an inherited Ubuntu 8.04 in shape. Has to run for 2 more years (company internal, so security not really an issue).

Trying to install tmux 1.9a from source (not in the repositories), but get error:

```
error: ‘EVBUFFER_EOL_LF’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

although configure worked without complaining (after installing some -dev packages).

How to solve this? (so used to tmux now that I don't want to go back to screen).
Or is there a repository I can download a tmux.deb from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot comment but the problem is that `tmux` configure doesn't check for which version libevent library you have installed. Ubuntu 8.04 had `libevent1` you need to install libevent2 (from source).

Download from libevent.org, the [last stable version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/levent/files/release-2.0.22-stable/libevent-2.0.22-stable.tar.gz).

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://sourceforge.net/projects/levent/files/release-2.0.22-stable/libevent-2.0.22-stable.tar.gz
gzip -d < libevent-2.0.22-stable.tar.gz | tar xf -
cd libevent-2.0.22-stable
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
ldconfig
```

and after that configure, compile and install tmux (I used an older 2.0 version, but this should solve your problem).

Comment: The 2.0 or 2.1 from http://libevent.org/ ?

Comment: I have used the 2.0 stable series, let me update the answer from my notes.